# Проторённая дорожка, но — идти проторЕнной дорожкой?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия, е-или-ё

Как правильно:

> идти протОр**енн**ой дорожкой

или

> идти протор**Ённ**ой дорожкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари дают только один вариант - **проторённый**. Проторенный - неправильно.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x

Оно понятно, исходный глагол - тор**и**ть, поводов для смещения ударения нет никаких.

Comment: _behemothus: исходный глагол  —  тор**и**ть, поводов для смещения ударения нет никаких_. === Какие-то поводы всё же могут быть. Во-первых, наличие _смещённого_ ударения у поэтов (к примеру, у Демьяна Бедного: _Держася формы четкой, строгой, / С народным говором в ладу, / Иду **протОренной** дорогой, / Речь всем доступную веду_.). Во-вторых, ударение на "О" в синониме прилагательного _проторённый_ : _**тОрный**_.  Но с этим   —  _"Словари дают только один вариант   —  проторённый"_  —  согласен.

Comment: Ну Бедного опустим, там поэтические вольности, а вот насчет "торный". Не думал как-то над этим. Не на слуху слово. Спасибо. Другой вопрос, основание ли это для смещения ударени при образование торить-проторить-проторённый. "Торный" - за скобками, т.е. за пределами цепочки.

Comment: _behemothus: Другой вопрос, основание ли это для смещения ударения при образовании **торить-проторить-проторённый**_. ===  Наверное, не основание. Но если бы в словарях было не _проторЁнный_, а _протОренный_,  мой слух такое ударение вряд ли  резало бы. Ну а по поводу смещения… К примеру, в похожей на Вашу цепочке ударение всё же смещается: _**топИть   — протопИть   — протОпленный**_.

Comment: Там в основе морф "топ" в нем фиксируются смещения и без этого случая. Но вообще-то мне уже как-то тяжело угнаться  за вашими примерами. Обозначьте тезис, если не трудно.

Comment: _behemothus: ...Обозначьте тезис, если не трудно_. === Тезис такой: из того, что в неопределённой форме глагола ударение стоит на _окончании_, не следует то, что в причастной форме этого глагола ударение не может сместиться на корень.  Ведь у каких-то глаголов такое смещение имеет место? Да и  _протОренный_, оказывается, не все словаристы категорически отвергают.  Нашёл у Горбачевича: _**проторЁнный**… и допустимо **протОренный**_.

Comment: *Тезис такой: из того, что в неопределённой форме глагола ударение стоит на окончании, не следует то, что в причастной форме этого глагола ударение не может сместиться на корень* - разумеется. Не следует. Тут даже спорить не о чем. Я **не выводил** отсутствие смещения из ударения в н. ф., я просто сообщал, что в данном случае не видно причин для такого смещения. И ваше тОрный было для меня неожиданным И вот с ним надо разбираться, согласен.

Comment: Про Горбачевича не знал, но тут он расходится с большинством авторов. Вот как раз в таких случаев и надо смотреть есть ли какие-то мотивы для такого смещения, т.е. как вообще ведет себя морф при словоизменении и словообразовании.